# How to change a property value with an onClick event in React

Tags: reactjs

Assume the following Component:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  func1 = () => {
  ....
    }

  func2 = () => {
  ...
    }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <Component
            activity={this.func1}
           />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

How can I implement an onClick event from the inside the Component function so as the result in the main App would be:

```
 <div>
   <Component
     activity={this.func2}
   />
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normal flow is as below

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  func1 = () => {
  ....
    }

  func2 = () => {
  ...
    }

  render() {
    return (
       <div>
          <Component
            activity={this.func1}
           />
      </div>
    );
  }
}


<div>
   <Component
     activity={this.props.activity(arguments)}
   />
 </div>
```

and doing this will have the activity prop call the func1 defined in the parent component..

Note:- ideally you should call a function as prop for events and not just normal attributes